# Why the keras code get error messages when changing from Keras 1.2.2 to Keras 2.0.5

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

This is a piece of code I get from github for hierarchical attention network,the code is originally in Keras 1.2.2. now I have to change it to compile with Keras 2.0.5, however, it has such error messages that I could not solve.

The original code is the following

```py
MAX_SENT_LENGTH = 100
MAX_SENTS = 20 
MAX_NB_WORDS = 276176
EMBEDDING_DIM = 128
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.1
# Feed the data
# Here you have source data

x_train = np.load('./data/X_full_train_data.npy')
y_train = np.load('./data/X_full_train_labels.npy')
x_val = np.load('./data/X_full_test_data.npy')
y_val = np.load('./data/X_full_test_labels.npy')

np.random.seed(10)
shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(y_train)))
x_train = x_train[shuffle_indices]
y_train = y_train[shuffle_indices]

shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(y_val)))
x_val = x_train[shuffle_indices]
y_val = y_train[shuffle_indices]



with open("./data/W.npy", "rb") as fp:
    embedding_weights = np.load(fp)


# here you feed embeding matrix        
embedding_layer = Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS,
                        EMBEDDING_DIM,
                        weights=[embedding_weights],
                        input_length=MAX_SENT_LENGTH,
                        trainable=True)
# building Hierachical Attention network

class AttLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.init = initializers.get('normal')

        super(AttLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape)==3
        self.W = self.init((input_shape[-1],))
        self.trainable_weights = [self.W]
        super(AttLayer, self).build(input_shape)  

    def call(self, x, mask=None):

        eij = K.tanh(K.dot(x, self.W))

        ai = K.exp(eij)
        weights = ai/K.sum(ai, axis=1).dimshuffle(0,'x')
        weighted_input = x*weights.dimshuffle(0,1,'x')
        ret = weighted_input.sum(axis=1)
        return ret

    #def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
    def compute_output_shape(self,input_shape):

        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])



sentence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENT_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)
l_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)

l_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(200))(l_lstm)
l_att = AttLayer()(l_lstm)
sentEncoder = Model(sentence_input, l_att)
review_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENTS,MAX_SENT_LENGTH), dtype='int32')
review_encoder = TimeDistributed(sentEncoder)(review_input)
l_lstm_sent = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(review_encoder)
l_dense_sent = TimeDistributed(Dense(200))(l_lstm_sent)
l_att_sent = AttLayer()(l_lstm_sent)
preds = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(l_att_sent)
model = Model(input=review_input, output=preds)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

print("model fitting - Hierachical attention network")
print(model.summary())

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))

predictions = model.predict(x_val)
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val,batch_size=32)
```

Then I have the following error

```py
textClassifierHATT.py:235: UserWarning: The `nb_epoch` argument in `fit` has been renamed `epochs`.

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textClassifierHATT.py", line 235, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1575, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 960, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 226, in get_updates
    accumulators = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 226, in <listcomp>
    accumulators = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 275, in int_shape
    raise TypeError('Not a Keras tensor:', x)
TypeError: ('Not a Keras tensor:', Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0)
```

the keras model compile succesfully in model.compile(), but it has error in model.fit(), I totally don't understand why such error exists. anyone can tell me how to modify it so that it can run with keras 2.0 Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the shape of your data

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes The shape of the data is just numpy arrary with (Trainsize,dimensions) and (Trainsize,label).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the build method of your custom layer, according to [keras' documentation](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/#writing-your-own-keras-layers), you need to create the weights with the `self.add_weight` function:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape)==3
        self.W = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                      initializer='normal',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(AttLayer, self).build(input_shape)
```

That and a few API changes:

- Parameter `input` and `output` changed in `Model(inputs=.., outputs=..)`
- The `nb_epochs` parameter in `fit` is now called `epochs`

Answer (score 0):

The data provided for training is not a tensor but fed as a numpy array. Try to convert the numpy arrays to tensor using :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.convert_to_tensor(
    value, dtype=None, dtype_hint=None, name=None
)
```

Then pass them to the model for training.